# Google cloud error: No agent on master node(s) found to be active in the past 300 seconds

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I am seeing an error in my Google Cloud logs : "No agent on master node(s) found to be active in the past 300 seconds" and I am not sure what is causing this.

I have a schedule in Google Cloud to run my queries and it has been running fine in months. Now when it should trigger a new Cloud Function I see the error.

Thanks

Comment: I have the same issue. The same Dataproc jobs were running for 4 years without this error and it suddenly started raising 8 RESOURCE EXHAUSTED No agent on master node(s) found to be active in the past 300 seconds.

Comment: Were you able to find any solution other than trying re-scheduling until it works?

Comment: Unfortunately no

Comment: I'm getting the same error when I launch a batch job using Spark Serverless. Have you found any resolution or explanation?

Answer (score 1):

I probably cannot help with OP's issue but for those coming here trying to submit their job in the Console on a recently started cluster: try to cancel the submit job procedure and start again.

I tried to submit a job without starting the cluster, received "cluster not active" error, started the cluster, tried to submit the job again and received exactly this message ("No agent on master node(s) found to be active in the past 300 seconds"). However, the error was resolved and I could submit the job, when I closed it, refreshed the page and started filling in the submit job form again.

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs if the agent on the Dataproc master node is not able to accept any new jobs. It may happen either due to the agent running out of memory or if the master VM node itself is unhealthy. This problem can be resolved by restarting (stopping, then starting) the Dataproc cluster or retrying the job submission later. More information regarding this error is found in the public documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/jobs/life-of-a-job#error_messages)